How do I await a coroutine within a non-async function in Python?
Consider this contrived example:
import asyncio

async def main():
    print(non_async_function())

def non_async_function():
    # Syntax error due to "await".
    return await async_function()

async def async_function():
    return "foo"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Since the await keyword cannot be used in a non-async function, how do I await an awaitable from a non-async function? asyncio.run and asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete don't work: RuntimeError: This event loop is already running.
asgiref.async_to_sync also doesn't work: RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.
This problem comes up with chained decorators where a decorator can provide both async and sync variants using inspect.iscoroutinefunction -- but if one of the decorators doesn't do this, subsequent decorators will mistakenly assume they're wrapping a sync function. A sync decorator can guard against this by checking the result (assuming it needs to operate on the result before returning it):
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
if inspect.isawaitable(result):
    return sync_await(result)

But how do I implement this sync_await in a way that uses the current async context with current context vars?

You can use asyncio.create_task in your non_async_function to add your async_function to the async event loop. Then you just need to gather your task(s) in main in order to collect the result(s)
import asyncio
from typing import Literal


async def main() -> None:
    result = await asyncio.gather(non_async_function())
    print(result)
    # prints ['foo'] (you get a list because of 'gather', even with only one task)


def non_async_function() -> asyncio.Task[Literal['foo']]:
    return asyncio.create_task(async_function())


async def async_function() -> Literal['foo']:
    return "foo"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


But I need the result inside the non-async function, so this doesn't help.

@KiranJonnalagadda Ah, I misunderstood - my apologies. I'm going to leave this here just in case it helps people coming from a search engine, if that's okay with you.

Sure. My answer isn't complete either. Why is this so hard?

I've found a working solution after a careful reading of PEP 492!
import asyncio
from collections.abc import Awaitable
from typing import TypeVar

_R_co = TypeVar('_R_co', covariant=True)

async def _coroutine_wrapper(a: Awaitable[_R_co]) -> _R_co:
    return await a

def sync_await(awaitable: Awaitable[_R_co]) -> _R_co:
    """Implement await statement in a sync context."""
    try:
        asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        return asyncio.run(_coroutine_wrapper(awaitable))

    a = awaitable.__await__()
    try:
        while (v := next(a)) is None:
            pass
        raise RuntimeError(f"Awaitable yielded unexpected value: {v!r}")
    except StopIteration as exc:
        return exc.value
    raise RuntimeError("Iterator did not raise StopIteration")  # pragma: no cover

Edit: Turns out this blocks the event loop, so it's not a good solution. I had to learn how Python's async works to understand why.
Generators were introduced way back in 2001 with Python 2.2 as a mechanism for stateful iterators. From the caller's perspective, a generator is like a class instance method that can be repeatedly called and holds state in the class instance, but the generator is actually a single function that exists in its own stack frame and interrupts its own control flow to yield a value.
PEP 380 in 2009 introduced sub-generator delegation with yield from, plus support for a final return value. That means result = yield from expr will pass through everything from expr but capture the return value.
PEP 492 builds on this. await expr is roughly the same as yield from expr -- the yielded values are now irrelevant and yielding is instead used to switch between tasks in the event loop.
My sync_await hack above captures these yields instead of yielding to upstream, so it blocks the event loop. To yield, sync_await must itself be a generator, which then passes responsibility to the calling function to yield those values again, all the way up to the async runner. Essentially, Python's async only works if every function in a chain of calls is an async function. Having even one non-async function in the chain will break async.
There's probably a way to call into internal functions of the event loop to mimic a yield, but this becomes implementation-specific and even the stdlib asyncio has distinct Python and C implementations. To be investigated...
